# Jar file too big

Tags: java, jar, size, windowbuilder

I created a simple project using WindowBuilder in Eclipse and my goal is to send it by email. I don't know what kind of computer the person is using, so I exported my project into a 'Runnable JAR File' and checked the option 'Extract required libraries into generated JAR'.

The problem is that the generated JAR file is 20MB in size!!! The project has only one simple window - nothing complicated or fancy.

I found that some people use ProGuard to include only what is really needed.

I would like to know if there is a way to optimize it 'manually'? Are there libraries that are automatically included when creating a WindowBuilder project, and how may I determine which libraries I can remove?

Thank you.

Comment: And why don't you just send the source code instead of the jar?

Comment: @fge: The receiver is not a coder. He is only interested in opening the app and use it.

Comment: The problem is that it is a shame for a coder to send a huge file of 20MB that has nothing complicated. If I do it using another language, the program will not exceed 100KB. 20MB for one window is not acceptable. So to repeat my question Is there a way, other than using ProGuard, to remove unnecessary libraries included by WindowBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same Problem using WindowBuilder. My solution was to look for the imports in my .java file, e.g.: `import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;`
In the Project Explorer in Eclipse you can see that there are much more imports than needed. Those 'Build Paths' can be removed carefully. 
Simply rightclick on a .jar import like "com.ibm.icu_52.1.0.v201404241930.jar" and click on "Build Path" and "Remove from Build Path". Unfortunately, you can't remove or delete the packages inside the .jars. 
But using this method, I managed to reduce the size from 20.7MB to 3.87MB. It's something...

Comment: Or use NetBeans. Such app takes only few KB.

Answer (score 0):

Like fge said, send the source. Or upload the `.jar` to [dropbox](http://dropbox.com) if you require you partner to access all of the files in the `.jar`.

If you don't like dropbox, find some other cloud storage solutions through a google search. Github or Bitbucket could also be an alternative to dropbox.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Eclipse plugin FatJar. FatJar shows you which libraries are getting imported and allows you to specify which .jars, libraries, etc., that you want built into your JAR.

[FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: ylun.za: Gmail allows 25MB attachments now.
my problem is not sending the email, but excluding unecessary libraries.

Comment: Updated with a solution in Eclipse.

Comment: But how can determine which libraries are not necessary for my file?
They have been included by WindowBuilder. Are they all necessary? Which libraries are unused?

Comment: I think your question needs clarification. You have to determine what is unnecessary to build into the JAR. It also depends what the nature of the system is that you're importing it into. If WindowBuilder generated some code for you - assume those to be pertinent libraries.

Comment: This precisely my question: how to determine the unused libraries generated by WindowBuilder.
No, WindowBuilder did't not create code for me.
The project include only one JFrame, one JTextField and a JButton.
Even if you create an ampty project using WindowBuilder it will be 20MB. You don't include 20MB of resources to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your jarfile is too big due of the project template. Create a sample java project, then use windowdbuilder components. Do not create a project Swing Template, by this way eclipse is gonna import all eclipse gui toolkits.

Tried it out with my way, my application's length equals to 3Ko against 24MO with the template project